# Как найти максимальную сумму между элементами возрастающей подпоследовательности?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Вот для примера : 96 24 48 27 3 144 75 144 48.  Ответ : 291. Ограничения N <= 10 ^ 5 и время 2 секунды.

[Ссылка на задачу](http://codeforces.com/contest/629/problem/D)

Comment: Очень просто: выделить все возрастающие подпоследовательности и сравнить их суммы. А если нужно просто сумму посчитать, так тут вообще в один проход можно управиться.

Comment: Еще кое - что ограничение n <= 10^5 и время 2 секунды. А я знаю алгоритм всех подпоследовательностей за N * N. Слишком долго.

Comment: Я слышал что тут можно использовать метод динамического программирования и использовать структуры данных . Но я не знаю как их использовать.

Comment: @Kurbanbayev, а ограничения на значения есть?

Comment: Если вы пишете «ограничение в 2 секунды», это сразу означает, что у вас не практическая задача, а вы хотите, чтобы мы за вас решили олимпиаду. Я бы просил участников проявить хоть немного сознательности и не давать копируемого кода, пусть более честные участники конкурса будут в равных условиях.

Comment: Это задача с CodeForces , а не олимпиада .

Comment: @Kurbanbayev: Это не практическая, а конкурсная задача. Ограничения в 2 секунды в реальной жизни не бывают. Мы тут помогаем решать реальные задачи. А в соревновании типа CodeForces должны участвовать вы лично, а не команда всего русскоязычного комьюнити StackOverflow. Это было бы нечестно по отношению к другим участникам соревнования.

Comment: Задача не сложна - решается за два прохода по массиву (можно улучшить и до одного, но алгоритм будет сложнее), но сначала покажите свою работу.

Comment: Это соревнование прошло пару месяцев назад , теперь я делаю дорешивание .

Comment: @Mirdin, не думаю. `10^5` - это `n*lb(n)`. Если бы решение было линейным, скорее всего поставили бы `10^6`. Квадратичное можно упихать `10^4` (и даже чуть больше), но не `10^5`.

Comment: @Kurbanbayev, может покажешь уже ссылку? Кстати, там же вроде после завершения контеста публикуется разбор задач? Или это не ко всем контестам относится?

Comment: http://codeforces.com/contest/629/problem/D

Comment: Правильный ответ, вроде бы должен быть 219, а не 291, что я делаю не так.

Comment: 291 это правильный :) 24, 48 , 75, 144

Comment: То есть могут быть пропуски, ок, тогда за линейное время не получится

Comment: Если было бы так просто я бы сам решил бы :)

Comment: Судя по ответу, вопрос сформулировано неверно.

Answer (score 4):

Общая идея ровно такая же, как и для обычной задачи где нужно максимизировать длину последовательности. Решается с помощью дерева отрезков или дерева Фенвика. Ссылки на идеи http://e-maxx.ru/algo/fenwick_tree http://e-maxx.ru/algo/segment_tree .

Нам нужно уметь быстро за (log n) находить ключ меньше данного с максимальным значением. (Эквивалентно поиску максимума на отрезке).

псевдокод

```
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    Tree.update(A[i], Tree.search(A[i]) + A[i] )
```

Ответ - максимум по всем A[i].
Там если что разбор есть по этой ссылке.

Ниже более развернуто.

а что именно непонятно?) Если вы разобрались как написать дерево, то осталось только написать данный цикл. Почему это так: если мы продолжаем последовательность то верно что предыдущий элемент был не больше текущего и из всех таких надо продолжать самую выгодную (по уже накопленной сумме). Почему 2 утверждение верно - от противного, пусть нам стало выгодно продолжить a1 <= a2 <= a3 ... <= C <= ... (C - текущий) и существует b1 <= b2 <= b3 <=... <= C такое что a1+a2+a3+... < b1+b2+b3+... (строгое отрицание 2 пункта), тогда мы можем заменить всю начальную цепочку  ai на bi что улучшит ответ -> получили противоречие. Следовательно жадный алгоритм корректен.

Алгоритм : берём текущий элемент C, смотрим все последовательности q1 <= q2 <= qn <=C , из всех таких выбираем с максимальной суммой q1+q2+...+qn её и пытаемся продолжить (если таких нет, то начинаем новую последовательность).

Заметим, что сама последовательность нас не интересует, нам нужно знать только её последний элемент и сумму членов.

Построим дерево, ключ - последний элемент, значение - сумма.

Теперь просто идём по массиву слева направо, находим максимум на отрезке (-inf, C] (если ничего нет, то полагаем ответ максимум 0). Изменяем значение текущего элемента на найденный максимум + C.

Ответ - максимум по всем A[i] из массива.
Сложность O(n log N) времени, O(n) или O(n log n) памяти (зависит от типа дерева).

Код не пишу специально.

Comment: Он не очень понятный :(

Comment: Можете по поподробнее объяснить ?

Comment: написал более подробно.

Comment: А в чем преимущество если использовать Дерево Фенвика ?

Comment: пишется быстрее, памяти меньше использует, если есть возможность то Фенвик почти всегда лучше любого другого дерева (но он применим не везде, где применимо дерево отрезков).

Answer (score 3):

Для каждого элемента нужно хранить максимальную сумму, заканчивающуюся строго в нём.

Нужно как-то для текущего элемента посчитать ответ за логарифм.

Предположу, что сработает помещение минимального последнего числа для данного ответа в `map`. Хотя не могу обосновать, что асимптотика будет приемлемой, поскольку придётся перебирать элементы из map'а в цикле до момента нахождения ответа.

Comment: Вы сможете код написать ?

Comment: @Kurbanbayev, с чего вдруг я должен писать код? Если бы я собирался написать этот код, я бы его на codeforces и отправил. Где у тебя к нему появится доступ, когда сам решишь.

Comment: @Kurbanbayev, зачем тебе решать задачи на codeforces, если ты не можешь по описанному алгоритму написать программу из двух циклов?

Comment: Просто вы написали что надо находить ответ за логарифм на каждый элемент . Я не знаю как это можно сделать. Поэтому спрашиваю код.

Comment: @Kurbanbayev, нет. Я написал, что _в идеале_ нужно за логарифм, а потом привёл идею с мутной ассимптотикой (помещение в map - логарифм, но для пересчёта для элемента будет цикл, колитчество итераций которого неизвестно), про который я предполагаю, что он уложится в условие "в среднем не более 10^3 действий".

Comment: sum[i] = (arr[i] > arr[i-1]) ? sum[i-1] + arr[i] : arr[i]; //фиксировное время

Comment: Беру слова обратно, неправильно понял задачу, за линейное время ее не решить.

Comment: Ну что поможешь решить ? У меня не получилось. Кажется у тебя решение не правильное или я криво написал.

Comment: @Kurbanbayev, time limit или нет?

Comment: Ну вроде правильно пишу и короче ответ не выходит правильный. Это как тупой перебор получается. Можешь сам код написать ? Потому что я вообще не уверен что у тебя идея правильная.

Comment: @Kurbanbayev, да в разборе описан другой алгоритм с лучшей асимптотикой. Но я не считаю, что этот может давать неверный ответ. TL - возможно, хотя мне кажется, что должно уложиться, но неверный ответ - это странно. Есть пример данных, на которых должен получиться неверный ответ?