# Как удалить из массива ненужные элементы ,чтобы он получился отсортированным?

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм

Есть класс с двумя целочисленными свойствами

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Есть список экземпляров класса List, отсортированный по второму свойству, например такой

```
1 1
7 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

Нужно удалить из него **как можно меньше элементов** так, чтобы не было повторений по первому свойству, чтобы не было повторений по второму свойству, он получился отсортирован не только по второму элементу, но и по первому, чтобы сумма разностей между этими элементами была наименьшей. То есть из списка выше должен получиться список

```
1 1
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

Comment: Ну это к математикам, вам нужен алгоритм по сути.

Comment: Вот есть похожий вопрос - посмотрите его http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506543/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: В конечном итоге список должен быть отсортирован сначала по первому свойству, затем, если имеем последовательность равных элементов второго свойства, тогда и по первому свойству? Во втором свойстве могут быть повторения? Почему вдруг удалился элемент 7 2? В первом списке нет семёрок.

Comment: @hedgehogues, 7 2 удалился потому что без семерке в первом свойстве останется больше элементов в конце

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил. Примера кода перед собой нет, но смысл в следующем. Создаем дерево со следующей структурой узлов.

```
int _index; // Индекс элемента массива
int _level; // Уровень узла в дереве
NodeType _parent; // Родительский узел
```

конструктор принимает массив элементов, индекс элемента в узле, и уровень текущего узла + 1

Корневой элемент имеет индекс -1. Далее мы создаем потомков из ВСЕХ элементов. Для каждого следующего элемента потомками будут те, которые (по индексу) идут после текущего и оба значения которых больше значений текущего. То есть у элемента 7 2 потомков уже не будет, потому что все первые элементы не больше семерки.

Если потомков нет, то отмечаем узле как лист (добавляем его куда нибудь в массив листов дерева). Далее от листа перемещаемся вверх (по полю `_parent`) и получаем результирующий массив. Так как в листе у нас есть поле `_level`, то мы сразу будем знать количество элементов в массиве. Самая длинная цепочка будет ответом.

Так же можно оптимизировать алгоритм и отбросить лишние варианты еще на этапе построения дерева. Например, можно добавлять в кэш максимальную длину цепочки (на том этапе, когда мы выясняем, что узел является листомм). И если мы выяснили, что после элемента (конечно же мы проверяем его по индексу, а не по значению) "2 6" у нас следует 2 элемента, то дойдя до того места, где у нас встречается этот элемент, мы сравниваем его уровень + кэшированное количество элементов после него с наибольшей на данный момент цепочкой, и если кэшированное значение больше, то отбрасываем этот вариант сразу. Есть возможность и еще сократить время действия алгоритма, но я их приводить уже не буду.

Comment: Э... как-то все слишком сложно.

Comment: Можно сделать все то же самое - но без дерева :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, можно, да.... алгоритм будет примерно таким же, как алгоритм проверки регулярок... то есть сначала двигаемся вперед, потом назад, потом вперед, потом назад... ну вы поняли ) А в моем случае требуется не просто найти первый правильный ответ, а выбрать один единственный, удовлетворяющий и другим условиям. И без дерево это все будет нечитабельно. И при добавлении новых условий отбора придется менять в нескольких местах код, а значит его надо будет заново переваривать )

Comment: Ничего подобного. Задача сводится к динамическому программированию, притом все подзадачи - жадные. И это при любом числе условий.

Comment: Иными словами, там просто два вложенных цикла.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, так предложите ваш вариант. Я не уверен, что два вложенных цикла будут проще в плане понимания кода (поддержки)

Comment: Какое-то сомнительное решение. Смахивает на перебор, хотя должна быть динамика...

Comment: @Qwertiy, какая динамика? Не понял

Comment: [Динамическое программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: @Qwertiy, в общем то почти все задачи решаются динамическим программированием уже довольно давно. Причем скорее всего это и от языка то не зависит. Как разбить данную задачу на еще более мелкие части я не знаю, но само это решение является мелкой частью более крупной задачи.

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct SequenceData {
        public int prevIndex;
        public int length;
        public int cost;
    }

    // ...
    // MyClass[] data = ...;

    Func<MyClass, MyClass, bool> canExtend = (a, b) => a.Prop1 < b.Prop1 && a.Prop2 < b.Prop2;
    Func<SequenceData, SequenceData, bool> compare = (a, b) => a.length > b.length || a.length == b.length && a.cost < b.cost;

    var seq = new SequenceData[data.Length];
    SequenceData best;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        best = new SequenceData { prevIndex = -1, length = 0, cost = 0 };

        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (canExtend(data[j], data[i]) && compare(seq[j], best))
            {
                best = seq[j];
                best.prevIndex = j;
            }

        best.length++;
        best.cost += Math.Abs(data[i].Prop1 - data[i].Prop2);
        seq[i] = best;
    }

    best = new SequenceData { prevIndex = -1, length = 0, cost = 0 };
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        if (compare(seq[i], best))
        {
            best = seq[i];
            best.prevIndex = i;
        }

    var result = new MyClass[best.length];
    for (int i = best.prevIndex, j = best.length - 1; i >= 0; i = seq[i].prevIndex, j--)
        result[j] = data[i];
```